# Writing data to the .txt files using SPIFFS in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino

I was keep trying to write some content to the .txt file placed in the current sketch folder but the file was not being overwritten... please help me and here is my code

```
#include "FS.h"
void setup() 
{     
  Serial.begin(115200);  
  Serial.println();   
  SPIFFS.begin();

  File configFile = SPIFFS.open("config.txt", "a+");

  if (configFile) 
  {
    configFile.println("HAI");
    Serial.println(configFile.readString());
  }

  configFile.close();  
}

void loop() 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code snip, you are doing a [SPIFFS](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/filesystem.md#file-system-object-spiffs) write into the on-board filesystem.

While running on a specific board, you cannot be able to write data to the source PC. To achieve this, run a [WebServer](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/FSBrowser/FSBrowser.ino) from your device to serve your file from a requested point.

Comment: Sir, I am very grateful for your answer, but I didn't get the essence of that FS browser example. And using this what I exactly want to do is "Store some data obtained from serial monitor to the file on my PC", So can you please give me some information or references regarding this...

Comment: When you run your code to Arduino or ESP8266, your computer is another machine in the network. So you need to transmit your data via networking methods like sockets. One of the easy way of data transfer is HTTP. You can run a WebServer in your computer and post data from ESP. Or you can run a TCP socket server on your computer as well. Do they mean anything to you ?